# How to check a condition at all time during java form is running?

Tags: java, netbeans, conditional-statements

Above question will get clear from below code
I am making a tic-tac-toe game in java (netbeans)

I have added if statement to see who is winner but I want it to tell on the spot , so that user could not proceed further ....

Below is player.java which allow user to input their name...

```
public class Player extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Player
     */
    public Player() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Stencil", 0, 48)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 15));
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("GAME CORNER");

        jLabel2.setText("Player 1's name");

        jLabel3.setText("Player 2's name");

        jButton1.setText("GO");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 380, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(56, 56, 56)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3))
                        .addGap(72, 72, 72)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 130, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1))
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(161, 161, 161))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 47, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(47, 47, 47)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(52, 52, 52)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(56, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        String p1 = jTextField1.getText();
        String p2 = jTextField2.getText();
        Tic_Tac_Toe t = new Tic_Tac_Toe(p1,p2);
        t.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Player.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Player.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Player.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Player.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Player().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Below is Tic_Tac_toe.java (game)

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author NEGI PC
 */
public class Tic_Tac_Toe extends javax.swing.JFrame {
int x=0;
String p1,p2;
    /**
     * Creates new form Tic_Tac_Toe
     */
    public Tic_Tac_Toe(String a,String b) {
        initComponents();
        p1 = a;
        p2 = b;

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
                formWindowOpened(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton6.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton8.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jButton9.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 153));
        jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton9ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton10.setText("WINNER");
        jButton10.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton10ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel1.setText("Player 1 turn");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 74, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(58, 58, 58)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 83, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 83, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(45, 45, 45))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(61, 61, 61)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 317, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(63, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 27, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 56, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 56, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         if(x==0){
        jButton2.setText("O");
        x=1;
        jLabel1.setText(p2+"'s Turn");
        }
        else{
        jButton2.setText("X");
        x=0;
        jLabel1.setText(p1+"'s Turn");
        }
         jButton2.setEnabled(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         if(x==0){
        jButton6.setText("O");
        x=1;
        jLabel1.setText(p2+"'s Turn");
        }
        else{
        jButton6.setText("X");
        x=0;
        jLabel1.setText(p1+"'s Turn");
        }
         jButton6.setEnabled(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        if(x==0){
        jButton1.setText("O");
        x=1;
        jLabel1.setText(p2+"'s Turn");
        }
        else{
        jButton1.setText("X");
        x=0;
        jLabel1.setText(p1+"'s Turn");
        }
         jButton1.setEnabled(false);
    }                                        

    private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jLabel1.setText(p1+"'s Turn");
    }                                 

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         if(x==0){
        jButton3.setText("O");
        x=1;
        jLabel1.setText(p2+"'s Turn");
        }
        else{
        jButton3.setText("X");
        x=0;
        jLabel1.setText(p1+"'s Turn");
        }
         jButton3.setEnabled(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         if(x==0){
        jButton4.setText("O");
        x=1;
        jLabel1.setText(p2+"'s Turn");
        }
        else{
        jButton4.setText("X");
        jLabel1.setText(p1+"'s Turn");
        x=0;
         }
         jButton4.setEnabled(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         if(x==0){
        jButton5.setText("O");
        x=1;
        jLabel1.setText(p2+"'s Turn");
        }
        else{
        jButton5.setText("X");
        x=0;
        jLabel1.setText(p1+"'s Turn");
        }
         jButton5.setEnabled(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         if(x==0){
        jButton7.setText("O");
        x=1;
        jLabel1.setText(p2+"'s Turn");
        }
        else{
        jButton7.setText("X");
        jLabel1.setText(p1+"'s Turn");
        x=0;
        }
         jButton7.setEnabled(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         if(x==0){
        jButton8.setText("O");
        jLabel1.setText(p2+"'s Turn");
        x=1;
        }
        else{
        jButton8.setText("X");
        x=0;
        jLabel1.setText(p1+"'s Turn");
        }
         jButton8.setEnabled(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton9ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
         if(x==0){
        jButton9.setText("O");
        x=1;
        jLabel1.setText(p2+"'s Turn");
        }
        else{
        jButton9.setText("X");
        x=0;
        jLabel1.setText(p1+"'s Turn");
        }
         jButton9.setEnabled(false);
    }                                        

    private void jButton10ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        if(jButton1.getText().equals("X")&&jButton2.getText().equals("X")&&jButton3.getText().equals("X")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton1.getText().equals("X")&&jButton5.getText().equals("X")&&jButton9.getText().equals("X")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton1.getText().equals("X")&&jButton4.getText().equals("X")&&jButton7.getText().equals("X")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton2.getText().equals("X")&&jButton5.getText().equals("X")&&jButton8.getText().equals("X")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton3.getText().equals("X")&&jButton6.getText().equals("X")&&jButton9.getText().equals("X")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton3.getText().equals("X")&&jButton5.getText().equals("X")&&jButton7.getText().equals("X")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton4.getText().equals("X")&&jButton5.getText().equals("X")&&jButton6.getText().equals("X")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton7.getText().equals("X")&&jButton8.getText().equals("X")&&jButton9.getText().equals("X")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton1.getText().equals("O")&&jButton2.getText().equals("O")&&jButton3.getText().equals("O")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton1.getText().equals("O")&&jButton5.getText().equals("O")&&jButton9.getText().equals("O")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton1.getText().equals("O")&&jButton4.getText().equals("O")&&jButton7.getText().equals("O")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton2.getText().equals("O")&&jButton5.getText().equals("O")&&jButton8.getText().equals("O")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton3.getText().equals("O")&&jButton6.getText().equals("O")&&jButton9.getText().equals("O")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton3.getText().equals("O")&&jButton5.getText().equals("O")&&jButton7.getText().equals("O")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton4.getText().equals("O")&&jButton5.getText().equals("O")&&jButton6.getText().equals("O")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else if(jButton7.getText().equals("O")&&jButton8.getText().equals("O")&&jButton9.getText().equals("O")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"It's a TIE !!!");
        }
    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tic_Tac_Toe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tic_Tac_Toe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tic_Tac_Toe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tic_Tac_Toe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Tic_Tac_Toe("","").setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I want that user should not need to press button to declare a winner...It should automatically declare with a type of "everytime for loop"...
Thanks in Advance...

Img of game interface :

[image]

Comment: You show a lot of code, but as for me, it is still not clear, what do you want. For example, here `if(jButton1.getText().equals("X")&&jButton2.getText().equals("X")&&jButton3.getText().equals("X")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }` you show your winner. What is wrong with that? You show that p2 won and, you don't want that player will press Ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you need to call the code that prints a winner automatically. For that you may call `jButton10ActionPerformed` from each and every `jButtonXXXActionPerformed`, where XXX is from 1 to 9. However, the code is suboptimal because there is a lot of copy - pasted code. Let's rewrite a little: 
Rename `jButton10ActionPerformed` to `findWinner` without arguments:

```
private void findWinner() {
        if(jButton1.getText().equals("X")&&jButton2.getText().equals("X")&&jButton3.getText().equals("X")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,p2+" is Winner");
        }
```

and put this code at the end of the function in comment, as otherwise a dialog will jump in your face after each turn:

```
 // else{
//            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane,"It's a TIE !!!");
//        }
```

Now let's rewrite all the `jButtonXXXActionPerformed`. See how I extract the button from the event and call `findWinner` at the end?

```
private void xoPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        JButton btn = (JButton) evt.getSource();
        if(x==0){
            btn.setText("O");
            x=1;
            jLabel1.setText(p2+"'s Turn");
        }
        else{
            btn.setText("X");
            x=0;
            jLabel1.setText(p1+"'s Turn");
        }
        btn.setEnabled(false);
        findWinner();
    }
```

Now go over all the code that calls `jButtonXXXActionPerformed` and replace it with `xoPerformed(evt);`. And replace `jButton10ActionPerformed` with `findWinner()`

Comment: Ok got it but what to do in a case no one win or it's a tie....Pls answer this question so that I can Accept this answer.

Comment: I got it....I have added``` else if(jButton1.getText()!=""&&jButton2.getText()!=""&&jButton3.getText()!=""&&jButton4.getText()!=""&&jButton5.getText()!=""&&jButton6.getText()!=""&&jButton7.getText()!=""&&jButton8.getText()!=""&&jButton9.getText()!=""){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "It's a TIE!!!");
        }``` to my program Thanks .... And do upvote my question!!!